# How to dump firmware from an SD card?

Tags: firmware, firmware-analysis, flash

I have an SD card that implements some strange [Write-Once-Read-Many](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write_once_read_many) technology that I want to check the firmware of. I'm not new to reverse-engineering, but I've never dumped firmware from an SD card before.

Any guidance on where to begin would be appreciated?

Comment: Have you tried to use one of hdd partition manager? This enables you to copy entire disk into another.

Comment: @MaciejLos: no I haven't. Would that allow me access to firmware though?

Comment: They can read firmware ID (number), etc. What kind of SD card do you have and why do you need to read firmware?